# How to check if an array contains all false values?

Tags: php, arrays

How to check if an array contains all `false` values?

```
$arr  = array(false, false, false);
$arr2 = array(true, false, false, 123);

check_false_array($arr);
true
check_false_array($arr2);
false
```

edit: not only `true`/`false` values are allowed

Comment: Rizier123, not necessarily the same question.

Comment: @George Why shouldn't it be? It shows exactly how to check, that an array only contains the same values

Comment: Array contains the same values vs Array contains the same of specific value, no?

Comment: I agree with George since this goes deeper as working with booleans changes this question enough to be considered different.

Comment: @George wow only to change: `if (count(array_unique($allvalues)) === 1 && end($allvalues) === 'true') {` to `if (count(array_unique($allvalues)) === 1 && end($allvalues) === FALSE) {` makes it a different question?

Comment: Well, yeah.. Having said that, the OP has shown no (research) effort of their own, so if anything it should be closed as off-topic.

Comment: @George So you really want to tell me, that changing one value in the entire code makes it not a duplicate?!

Comment: IMO yeah. While that change to get the solution might be obvious to you or me, it might not be to the person asking the question.

Comment: @George So you wouldn't close any question with this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8881719/3933332 only because they have to change one freaking value. So we would end up with thousands of `in_array()` answers just with different values. I completely disagree here, but don't want to discuss here in the comments, so I will end it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php). `array_filter()` will remove all false values and if `empty()` returns true you have all false values.

```
function check_false_array(array $array) {
    return empty(array_filter($array, 'strlen'));
}

var_export(check_false_array(array(false, false, false)));
echo "\n";
var_export(check_false_array(array(false, true, false)));
echo "\n";
var_export(check_false_array(array(0,0,0)));
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/403130)

If you want `0` to be considered `false` just remove the callback to `'strlen'` in `array_filter()`.

[Demo](https://eval.in/403136)

Comment: What if the array is `array(0,0,0)`?

Comment: @b0s3 *"all false values"* would imply *any* falsey value - maybe that's just me.

Comment: If you pass `'strlen'` to `array_filter()` it will correctly handle this. See the demo.

Comment: @George `array(false, false) !== array(false, 0)` OR `false !== 0`. AFAIK.

Comment: @b0s3 That wasn't my argument.

Comment: @George I am just pointing out the chances as OP did not mention this. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_filter` with a callback for identical match to `false` & `empty` to check.

```
$arr  = array(false, false, false);
$check = array_filter($arr, function($x) {
  return ($x !== false);
});

if(empty($check)) // $check will be empty if all the value is false (only false)
```

Answer (score -1):

these two functions will check for what you need, assuming the arrays can only have "true" or "false" and nothing else

```
function isFalseArray($arr){
    foreach($arr as $a){
        if($a == "true")
           return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function isTrueArray($arr){
    foreach($arr as $a){
        if($a == "false")
           return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```